# Youtube API: How to grab video ID? JQuery/Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Currently fetching the first video from a search on YouTube using the code below, but when docready is called, the ids are not set. The code does not wait for the ajax results to be returned, instead it continues and returns nothing.

I've tried the async:false with the ajax thinking it might make it 'wait' but still nothing is returned. How would I fix this so all the ids will be set?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    docready();
});

function docready() {
    var id1 = grabid("cat");
    var id2 = grabid("dog");
    var id3 = grabid("goldfish");
    alert(id1);
}

function grabid(keyword) {
    var url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + encodeURIComponent(keyword) + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc';
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (responseData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (responseData.data.items) {
                var videos = responseData.data.items;
                videoid = videos[0].id;
                alert(videoid);
                return videoid;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've just changed the code above a bit to make my problem a bit clearer. When the code is run it alert's the real 'videoid' 3 times as expected. But when it gets to alert(id1) it returns undefined - so the 'return videoid' is ignored and not passing it back to the variable.

**UPDATE 2 STILL UNSOLVED**

Comment: Can you show us the most important part -- the JSON encoded response.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be relevant? When I add alert(videoid) before the return it does so, so it's getting the data ok.

Comment: Anyway...........`id=grabid(keyword1)` what is keyword1? is that variable set somewhere else globally? it's not provided nor in the scope of the docready function. You're passing over a variable `keyword1` to the function, which uses `keyword1` in the component string. Is this the correct variable? You haven't provided it, so it's tough to debug. You said that the `response is not waiting`, but any code that is properly invoked will have a foot print. Do you know how to use a web inspector? Check the XHR request to see if it's ran. If not, do you know what `breakpoints` are?

Comment: I asked prematurely, because I assumed the title of the question was your aligned with your needs. This isn't, however, about the API, as much as it is about getting functions to pass variables.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy you're right. But the title was named so to attract people who are familiar with the YouTube API and might have experience with the issue I'm facing. I've updated my code example in light of your comments. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have problem with your ajax call try this..

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: function (responseData) {
                  var videos = responseData.data.items;
                  var videoid=videos[0].id;
                   alert(videoid);
                  //pass this videoid to anyother JS function it should work
                },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                 alert(xhr.responseText);
                }   

 });
```

EDIT:

Updated code to get return from ajax call :

```
 function grabid(keyword){
   var url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+encodeURIComponent(keyword)+'&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc';
  return $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     dataType: "jsonp"       
    });   

}



function getVideoId(key) {
  key.success(function(respdata) {
      var videos = respdata.data.items;
      var videoid=videos[0].id;
     alert(videoid)
   });
  }

var ids = grabid(123);
getVideoId(ids);
```

Remove all your onload or document ready functions,this should work.

EDIT :

The only thing you can do is doing async:false, which will wait for the ajax call to finish and return a value... but CROSS DOMAIN calls are not synchronous so I can say you are out of luck.. You need to re think on the logic of ajax calls.

Also As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.

Comment: I'm using the same keywords as above. Unfortunately I need it to return the videoid so it can be used in the docredy function, not pass it to another (as the code above can already do this). Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks again, but when I run that I'm getting 'key is undefined'. Added for you to check on http://jsfiddle.net/9wC2a/

Comment: @user1516606 : Sorry mate Cant reproduce the same from my side.. I have tested the same above code in IE,chrome and mozilla .. every thing is fine ..

Comment: Ah brilliant. I was loading Jquery via 'google.load' - changed it to the cdn link and it seems to have fixed the issue. You're a genius, been trying to work this out for so long.  Thank you :)

Comment: @user1516606 : Glad it did work for you.. you can accept the anwser :) by ticking the arrow mark :)

Comment: Ah, with the excitement of thinking this was finally solved I overlooked the fact that the alert was in the "getVideoId" function. It looks so close though, I've played around with it a bit but can't get it to work. You see I need the videoid to be accessed outside of that function. So the last line of your current code should be something like var id=getVideoId(); then I should be able to play with the id and use it in other functions.

Comment: Thanks for all your time. CROSS DOMAIN calls are not synchronous seems to be the killer here. Appreciate your research.

Comment: @user1516606 : Yes as i told you you need to re-think on your logic ..one workaround maybe making a synchronous Ajax call to your own domain and then making the cross-domain call from your server - is the best approach you could take if you really want it to be synchronous...and remember still for synchrnoous you need to set async:false; which leads to many issues such has hanging browser

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used the following (caveat: stripped out a bunch of other code, so this may not run as-is)

```
function getVideos(playlistID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" + playlistID + "?v=2&alt=json",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    processData: true,
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: loadVideos
                });
}

function loadVideos (data) {

        if (data && data.feed && data.feed.entry) {
            var markup = '<ul>';
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function (index) {
                var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.media$group.yt$videoid.$t + '?rel=0&wmode=transparent',
                    title = this.title.$t,
                    thumb = this.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
                markup += "<li><a data-rel='videos' href='" + url + "' target='_blank' class='youtube' title='" + title + "'><img src='" + thumb + "' alt='" + title + "' /></a></li>";
            });
            markup += '</ul>';


    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid calling a function from within a function. The purpose of the question was to try and figure out how to return the video id into a variable (while waiting for ajax to return the results).

Comment: Not when you need to re-use the videoid for multiple purposes.

Answer (score 0):

ok here's what I tried that seemed to work

```
function grabid(query) {
var yurl ='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos';
yurl = yurl+'?key=<GDATA API KEY>';
yurl = yurl+'&orderby=relevance';
yurl = yurl+'&start-index=1';
yurl = yurl+'&max-results=1';
yurl = yurl+'&v=2';
yurl = yurl+'&q='+encodeURI(query);

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: yurl,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

var ytvideo = {
    ttl:title,
    vid:videoid,
    thm:thumb,
    vws:views,
    dur:duration
}
return ytvideo;
}

function parseXml(xml) {
$(xml).find("entry").each(function() {
    title = $(this).find("title").text();
    thumb = $(this).find("media\\:thumbnail, thumbnail").attr("url");
    videoid = $(this).find("yt\\:videoid, videoid").text();
    duration = $(this).find("yt\\:duration, duration").attr("seconds");
    views = $(this).find("yt\\:statistics, statistics").attr("viewCount");
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is function scope, what is your ajax callback function returning to? It's not where you'd think it might be. Why dont you create an array in scope of all functions and assign the id's to that. Example below (untested)

```
// Id array in scope of all functions in this script
var id = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    docready();
});

function docready() {
    // Removed vars as all id's are in the id array. Just grab what you want
    grabid("cat");
    grabid("dog");
    grabid("goldfish");

    // Alert the 'cat' item in the id array
    alert(id['cat']);
}

function grabid(keyword, success_callback) {
    var url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + encodeURIComponent(keyword) + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc';
    $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (responseData.data.items) {
            var videos = responseData.data.items;

            // Assign the video ID for the keyword to (array)id
            id[keyword] = videos[0].id;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately still returning undefined! I had an idea of something like that but didn't think it would work because alert(id['cat']); is still being called way before the 'success' of ajax. Javascript just seems to ignores it and move on with the function. Almost thought you had it there tho, thanks for trying.